# Como obtengo el "SI" o "NO" de este input? Angular

Tags: angular, angular8

```
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="SI" data-off="NO" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-width="50" data-height="1" data-size="mini" formControlName="SiNo">
```

En el component tengo eso: 
    altaForm: FormGroup;

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.altaForm = new FormGroup({
  SiNo: new FormControl('', Validators.required)

  });
```

}

Lo que necesito es saber el valor SI o NO, y siempre me llega vacío...

Answer (score 2):

Estás usando un FormGroup, pero no has declarado en tu plantilla el uso del mismo. Tienes dos opciones:

- Si sólo vas a usar un checkbox y no hay más campos, no necesitas un FormGroup, puedes hacer algo como lo siguiente:

  ```
  <input type="checkbox" [formControl]="SiNo">
  ```

  Y en el código del componente hacer:

  ```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.SiNo = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    this.Sino.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      // Hacer algo con el nuevo valor
    });
  }
  ```
- Si vas a tener más campos en el formulario (en el FormGroup), necesitas declararlo:

  ```
  <form novalidate [formGroup]="altaForm">
    <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="SI" data-off="NO" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-width="50" data-height="1" data-size="mini" formControlName="SiNo">
  </form>
  ```

  El atributo `formGroup` no tiene por qué estar en una etiqueta `<form>`, puedes ponerla en un div o span, pero lo habitual es usar form.

Puedes ver un pequeño tutorial sobre los formularios reactivos en español [aquí](https://codingpotions.com/angular-formularios)

Comment: Ya tengo eso en el form por que si, tendré más. Pero solo he puesto esos por que son los únicos campos que me llegan vacíos. Los demás si que llegan

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes cambiar en tu codigo en la parte del .ts, es lo siguiente:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.altaForm = new FormGroup({
  SiNo: new FormControl('', Validators.requiredTrue)

  });
```

al obtener el formulario observaras el valor que tiene en tu input